# Convert slim to ERB

Tags: ruby, sinatra, erb, slim-lang

I am making my first steps in ruby and I am trying to learn how to use Sinatra. In a relevant book I found this example view written in Slim.

```
h1 Songs
a href="/songs/new" Create a new song
- if @songs.any?
  ul#songs
    -@songs.each do |song|
      li <a href="/songs/#{song.id}">#{song.title}</a>
- else
  p No songs have been created yet!
```

I tried to change it into ERB ending up in something like this

```
<html>
<h1> Songs </h1>
<a href="/songs/new" Create a new song></a>
<% if @songs.any? %>
    <%#songs%>
    <% @songs.each do |song|%>
        <ul><li> <a href="/songs/#{song.id}"><%=#{song.title}%></a></li></ul>
<% else %>
    <p> No songs have been created yet!</p>
<% end %>   
</html>
```

Sinatra gave me this report

```
SyntaxError at /songs
Documents/programs/sinatra/views/songs.erb:8: syntax error, unexpected keyword_else, expecting ')' ; else ^ 
Documents/programs/sinatra/views/songs.erb:10: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting ')' ; end ; @_out_buf.concat "\t\n" ^ 
Documents/programs/sinatra/views/songs.erb:14: syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting ')' 
Documents/programs/sinatra/views/songs.erb:16: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting ')'
```

Can you give me a clue of what is going on?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put another `<% end %>` right after your `<ul>...` line (before the `<% else %>`).

In Slim, the end of the `@songs.each` loop is implied by the indentation, but in ERB you need to explicitly `end` it.

Also, you will need to use ERB tags in your `<a>` element too. And you'll probably want the `<ul>` outside of the list. Here's what the the whole thing should probably look like:

```
<ul>
  <% @songs.each do |song| %>
    <li><a href="/songs/<%= song.id %>"><%= song.title %></a></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you very much Dylan.You have been very helpful!